# ESP32-C3 USB not working with Android

Tags: esp8266, esp32, usb-c

I want to connect an ESP32-C3 mini board (pictured below) to an Android phone, so that it can do all the WiFi stuff that Android no longer allows. The board works fine connected to my desktop computer using a USB-A to USB-C cable, appearing on the computer as a USB serial port, but it does not work connecting to an Android phone using a USB-C to USB-C cable.

The same problem occurs with an ESP8266 board that has a USB-C socket. An ESP8266 with a micro-usb socket works fine with the phone using a a USB-C to micro-usb cable.

Is this something to do with the way USB-C connections work? Is there a solution?

[image]

here is the schematic:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have a schematics for this board? Does the board have 5.1k pull-downs on CC1 and CC2 pins of the Type-C connector? Does the board see VBUS +5V power?

Comment: The schematic is only available as a PDF, so I have screen snipped as much as I can. Yes, CC1 and CC2 are pulled up. Yes VBus is connected to the input of the regulator (shown on full schematic but outside this clip)

Comment: The schematics are missing a lot of parts. Please provide full schematics. Or you could at least said which board that is, like the photo matches WaveShare, but schematics do not. Also what kind of Type-C to Type-C cable you use between phone and this board? Is it a passive or active cable? Did you try all 4 combinations of how to flip the connectors on both devices?

Comment: @Justme The schematic is missing just two parts. I have now added them as a separate image. The board is an unbranded clone, which does work fine with a type A to type C cable but not with type C to type C. I tried three different passive cables- one of the three works if I replace the magnetic type C tip with a micro-usb tip and connect it between an android device and a Wemos or an ESP32 fitted with a micro-usb. I did not try the USB cable in different orientations/directions: I thought that the whole point of type C is that the cable is symmetrical.

Comment: @JavaLatte The cable and devices are supposed to be symmetrical. In real life, you might end up with cheap non-USB-compliant garbage that works only in one orientation, especially with these unbranded clones, or they only work when force-fed with e.g. Type-A to Type-C cable. Have you verified that the schematics match the hardware, and that resistors R1 and R2 are both actually present and have 5k1 resistance to ground? One thing is that this device likely breaks the inrush current/energy limit of USB standards by having a lot of 10uF capacitors. The phone could give up to protect itself.

Comment: @JavaLatte Magnetic type? Sounds suspicious. They may leave out pins, and are otherwise non-compliant cables, as you can easily violate the order how pins attach between devices. If you use Type-A plug to Type-C plug magnetic cable, it will expose the connector pins to static electricity and short circuits, and if you manage to connect 5V supply and data pins before ground, that can do damage. I would never use those magnetic cable adapters for these reasons. Use a real cable which is guaranteed to be USB compliant.

Comment: "Yes VBus is connected" I was asking, is there +5V voltage when you plug it in?

Comment: Also, did you try a different phone? Did you try a host with USB-C port and your C-C cable? Are you sure your C-C cable supports USB communication, or it is just a charging cable with no D+/D- wires?

Comment: Thank you @Ale..chenski for your helpful questions: they started me on the thread that led to an understanding of the problem. I'm going to close this question now, as it's not a real problem. Ah, can't do that: presumably I don't have enough kudos for that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what happens.

When you connect the ESP32-C3 to the phone, the power light comes on and the terminal app reports that a USB device is available. You tell the app to connect to the device, then you tell Android to let the app connect to the device. By this time, the bootloader output and the app's initial prompt have long gone.

This isn't a problem for devices other than ESP32-C3: you can just press reset on the device, and then you see all of the startup output. That works because the USB connection is via an external chip, for example a CH340. With the ESP32-C3, when you press reset, the USB connection is dropped and you have to go once more through the connection procedure, by which time...

The ESP8266 Wemos board doesn't work for a different reason: when you connect it to the phone, it doesn't get power. Presumably it fails to meet the connection requirements for USB-C to USB-C.